# Responsive boxes with a sticky/responsive button at the bottom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

(First time using Stack Overflow, let me know if I've made any grave social errors)

[I've created a fiddle here of what I've been working on so far](https://jsfiddle.net/95b18u9q/#&togetherjs=RmHEgrjOCG) https://jsfiddle.net/95b18u9q/#&togetherjs=RmHEgrjOCG

Here's what I want:

- Three boxes, each with three parts: header, description, and footer, arranged vertically
- In desktop, these will be arranged so they're all in a row
- In mobile, they'll be arranged so they're in columns, widening so they take up more width
- Buttons *aligned* in desktop (row) format (like the bottom row of a table), but just underneath the description in mobile (column) format

Here's what's causing problems:

- That fourth bullet: I want the register buttons to be aligned in desktop format (row). But when in mobile format (columns), I want them to shrink to be just below the item description (this is why I can't just manually adjust row height; the columns would be too long in mobile format)
- I would use a table, but that wouldn't have the responsive row -> column format (or would it? I'm teaching myself responsive design, still learning)
- Right now, the shorter columns have the buttons covering up some
  description when in mobile form

I've figured out some fixes, but they're causing problems.

- Flexboxes are better than  whatever was going on before, with tables.
  But this solution is making the boxes take up however much space they
  want. I want three columns or one column.
- Another glitchy fix: I'm using position: absolute for the longest box, and
  position: relative for the shorter ones. That's getting the boxes to
  be long enough so the buttons align in desktop mode, but position: relative boxes have buttons overlapping the description in mobile form. (It seems like a bit of a clumsy solution, too: I have to always know and mark the longest box)

The HTML

```
<div class="pricing-container">
    <div class="item-container" >
        <div class="item-header">Column 1</div>
        <div class="item-description">
            <ul>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- The longest column needs position: relative. All others do not. -->
        <div class="item-footer" style="position: relative;">NewRegister</div>
    </div>


    <div class="item-container" >
        <div class="item-header">Column 2</div>
        <div class="item-description">
            <ul>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="item-footer" style="">NewRegister</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-container">            
        <div class="item-header">Column 3</div>
        <div class="item-description">
            <ul>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="item-footer" style="">NewRegister</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.pricing-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
align-items:stretch;

}

.item-container {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
align-items:stretch;
position:relative;
align:row;
    width:33%
}

.item-header {
    background-color:gray;   
}
.item-description{
    width:90%;
}
.item-footer {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
}
@media(min-width:787px) {
.item-container{
width:33%
}
}
@media(max-width:786px) {
.item-container{
width:100%
}
}
```

Comment: For a first time posted you did what most people don't do... The right thing! thank you for posting your code, what you have tried and a detailed question.

Comment: How is this? https://jsfiddle.net/BradHouston/95b18u9q/1/

Comment: @BradHouston It's got the sticky footers, but they aren't aligned in desktop/row format... Thank you for the solution, it does get the responsive part down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this ticks most of the boxes you wanted.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WvPapV?editors=110)

```css
.pricing-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.item-container {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item-header {
  background-color: gray;
}
.item-description {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.item-footer {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .pricing-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .item-container {
    flex: 0;
  }
  .item-description {
    flex: 0;
  }
  .item-footer {
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-header">Column 1</div>
    <div class="item-description">
      <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- The longest column needs position: relative. All others do not. -->
    <div class="item-footer" style="position: relative;">NewRegister</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-header">Column 2</div>
    <div class="item-description">
      <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item-footer" style="">NewRegister</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-header">Column 3</div>
    <div class="item-description">
      <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item-footer" style="">NewRegister</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is it! It has everything responsive and with the buttons aligned! I don't even know how you did this, I'll have to go through the code and figure out what sorcery this is.

Comment: Edit: I think the magic happens here:

To make the footer stick to the bottom, where ever that may be:
'.item-description {
    flex: 0;
  }
.item-footer {
//desktop mode//
align-self: flex-end;}
{//mobile mode //
    align-self: flex-start;
  }'